# how to send payload as multipart/form to request in mule4

Tags: multipartform-data, dataweave, mulesoft

i transform a payload need to send as as multipart/form to request.
the payload is like below

```
{
"goods_id": "12345,
"color_id_1": 20,
"image_id_1": vars.png1,   //this is binary ,image data
"color_id_2": 11,
"image_id_2": vars.png1,   //this is binary ,image data
}
```

here is sample file which we need to transform, the file is base on postman script.
in postman we can choose image file from notebook.  in payload, the image is an object
which is stored in variable .

```
POST /cooperate/RegistAllImage HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------549967118512544277394909
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: ddddd
Host: ddddd
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: *****
Content-Length: 40980
 
----------------------------549967118512544277394909
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="goods_id"
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
12345
----------------------------549967118512544277394909
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="color_id_1"
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
20
----------------------------549967118512544277394909
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_1"; filename="064df7cefee0421990ccb74a5c1f9ccf.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
<064df7cefee0421990ccb74a5c1f9ccf.jpg>
----------------------------549967118512544277394909
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="color_id_2"
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
2
----------------------------549967118512544277394909
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_2"; filename="064df7cefee0421990ccb74a5c1f9ccf.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
<064df7cefee0421990ccb74a5c1f9ccf.jpg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can very well use the Multipart form module or can construct the parts using the script below.

```
%dw 2.0
import dw::module::Multipart    
output multipart/form-data boundary="--------------------------549967118512544277394909"
---
{
  parts: {
    part1: Multipart::field({
      name: "goods_id",
      value: payload.goods_id,
      mime: "appliation/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      
    }),
     part2: Multipart::field({
      name: "color_id_1",
      value: payload.color_id_1,
       mime: "appliation/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    })
    ,
     part3: Multipart::field({
      name: "image_id_1",
      value: payload.image_id_1,
      mime: "appliation/octet-stream",
      fileName: "064df7cefee0421990ccb74a5c1f9ccf.jpg"
    })
    ,
     part4: Multipart::field({
      name: "color_id_2",
      value: payload.color_id_2,
       mime: "appliation/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    })
    ,
     part5: Multipart::field({
      name: "image_id_2",
      value: payload.image_id_2,
      mime: "appliation/octet-stream",
      fileName: "064df7cefee0421990ccb74a5c1f9ccf.jpg"
    })
  }
}
```

Answer to the question in comment:

```
%dw 2.0
import dw::module::Multipart    
output multipart/form-data boundary="--------------------------549967118512544277394909"
---
{
  parts: payload mapObject ((value, key, index) ->   {
    ("part" ++ ((index)+1)): Multipart::field({
      "name":  key as String,
      "value": value as String,
      "mime": if(key startsWith "image_id_") "application/octet-stream" else         "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      ("fileName": "filenmae.png" )if(key startsWith "image_id_") 
    
  })
  })
}
```

Comment: may i know how to dynamic to show each field?  as there maybe have many fields nee to be send.

Comment: The script has a type. It says `appliation/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [Multipart dataweave module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-multipart) that will make it fairly simple.
You will need [`Multipart::form`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-multipart-functions-form) function to create the form, and pass an array of all the fields, that you have in your payload. I have used `pluck` for it and then mapped it using [`Multipart:field`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-multipart-functions-field) function to get an Array of type [`MultipartPart`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-multipart-types). Your transform module will look like this

```js
%dw 2.0
import dw::module::Multipart
output multipart/form-data
---
Multipart::form(
    payload pluck ((value, key) -> 
        if(key as String startsWith "image_id_")
           Multipart::field(key as String, value, "application/octet-stream")
        else Multipart::field( key as String, value as String)
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks. if there have many field like _3, _4, how to to dynamic to list this form data from payload

Comment: It will depend on the input, that can tell how do you know how many fields you need? How is the different color ids and images defined in those input? Do you have to send the same image for all color ids?

Comment: the counts of fields denpend on the source payload, each color_id may have multiple different images,  each goods_id may have multiple color_id

Comment: Oh, so the payload that you have shared is the actual input and it is dynamic, meaning the _1, _2 fields can be as many as possible?

Comment: yes. basically , one goods_code has 4-8 color_id,  one color_id has 9-15 image.