# Problem with posting multipart/form-data in mule-4 while it was running fine in mule-3

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

I am migrating a application from mule-3 to mule-4. Facing issue while posting multi-part/form-data
in mule-4. mule-3 configuration is like this for setting attachments of multipart form data. first in mule-3 i am getting base64 from a http component which looks like below.

step-1:
[image]

and after that. I am using transform message component to decode the payload

step-2:
[image]

then the calling the following flow for posting data

```
 <flow name="wbg_ebiz_wfa_wb_docs_upload_attachments">
        <set-payload value="#[null]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        
                <set-attachment attachmentName="SITE_KEY" value="#[flowVars.dotnetVar.SITE_KEY]" contentType="text/plain" doc:name="SITE_KEY"/>
            
        <set-attachment attachmentName="I4_KEY" value="#[flowVars.dotnetVar.Key]" contentType="text/plain" doc:name="I4_KEY"/>
        <set-attachment attachmentName="I4_XML" value="#[flowVars.dotnetVar.metadata]" contentType="text/plain" doc:name="I4_XML"/>
        <set-attachment attachmentName="I4_APP_ID" value="ESB_BUSINESS" contentType="text/plain" doc:name="I4_APP_ID"/>
        <set-attachment attachmentName="#[flowVars.dotnetVar.FileName]" value="#[sessionVars.dotnetResVar]" contentType="binary/octet-stream" doc:name="File Attachment"/>
        <logger message="#[flowVars.dotnetVar.FileName]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-attachment attachmentName="fileName" value="#[flowVars.dotnetVar.FileName]" contentType="text/plain" doc:name="FileName"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_WB_DOCS_Request_Configuration" path="/services" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP">
            <http:request-builder>
                <http:query-param paramName="I4_SERVICE" value="ADD_DOC"/>
                <http:header headerName="HOST" value="aa.cc.org"/>
                <http:header headerName="Authorization" value="#[flowVars.access_token]"/>
                <http:header headerName="Content-Type" value="multipart/form-data"/>
            </http:request-builder>
            <http:success-status-code-validator values="100..550"/>
        </http:request>
        <logger message="payload from wbdocs #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

in mule-4 up to step-1 is fine. am able to get base64 string i tried to decode base 64 string using the following code

[image]

then after that I used the follwing code to construct parts

```
%dw 2.0
import dw::module::Multipart    
output multipart/form-data 
---
{
  "parts": {
    "I4_KEY":{
        "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        "Content-Disposition": {
          "name": "I4_KEY",
          subtype: "form-data"
              },
         
          },
        
      "content": vars.I4_KEY as String
    },
    "SITE_KEY": {
        "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        "Content-Disposition": {
          "name": "SITE_KEY" as String,
          subtype: "form-data"
              },
         
          },
      "content": vars.SITE_KEY as String
    },
    "I4_APP_ID": {
        "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        "Content-Disposition": {
          subtype: "form-data",
          "name": "I4_APP_ID" as String
              },
         
          },
      "content": "ESB_EBUSINESS" as String
    },
    "I4_XML": {
        "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        "Content-Disposition": {
          subtype: "form-data",
          "name": "I4_XML" as String
              },
         
          },
      "content": vars.I4_XML as String
    },
    "fileName": {
        "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        "Content-Disposition": {
          subtype: "form-data",
          "name": "fileName" as String
              },
         
          },
      "content": "Togo Country ASL.pdf"
    },
    "Togo Country ASL": {
      "headers": {
        
        "Content-Disposition": {
            "name": "Togo Country ASL",
             subtype: "form-data",
             "filename": "Togo Country ASL.pdf"
           
        },
         "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
        
        
      },
      "content":  read(vars.dotnetResVar, "application/octet-stream")
    }
  }
}
```

this payload for multipart/form-data request in mule-4  throwing 500 internal server error.

Comment: I am not very familiar with mule 3's `set-attachment`. But from your mule 4 transformation it looks like it will create your multipart request. If that is correct then the recommended way of creating multipart payload in mule 4 is using [dw-multipart](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-multipart) and not defining the whole structure like you are trying. [Maybe this question helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73145713/how-to-send-payload-as-multipart-form-to-request-in-mule4)

Comment: Please do post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: Where are the variables being defined in the Mule 4 flow? You should provide the flow or at least enough context to understand what is going on. You should also enable HTTP wire logging in both versions (https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-Enable-HTTP-Wire-Logging) to compare the results and confirm the data is similar enough.